# Fazer sessão expirar após 5 minutos de inatividade

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, codeigniter, session

Olá, estou perdida nessa lógica, estou usando codeigniter, e estou tentanto expirar a sessão após 5 minutos de inativade (caso o usuário fique sem acessar a página por até 5 minutos), arrumei o código, e criei uma lógica com ajax, assim que o usuario faz o login eu gravo o time no banco de dados da seguinte forma:

> $dadosSessao['ultima_atividade'] = time()+(5 * 60);

na tabela do meu banco sessão gravo o time no campo ultima_atividade, e verifico com o ajax de 1 em 1 minuto consultando o controller Area_usuario o tempo da ultima atividade de session:

> $lastVisitTime  = $_SESSION['last_visited'];

e comparo com o time gravado no banco ultima_atividade, e se for menor ou igual ao ultimo time gravado no banco eu dou um update no banco aumentando o time, até ai beleza, fiz o código ele fica atualizando o time no banco de 1 em 1 minuto, e não funciona nada, mesmo se eu deixar a janela inativa por mais de 5 minutos ele não executa a expiração, não sei o que ta acontecendo se puderem me ajudar agradeço.

Meu código está assim, esse é meu controler Area_usuario:

```
 //verificar inatividade de sessão
      public function verificarInatividade()
      {
          $vetor = $_SESSION['usuarioLogado'];
          $email = $vetor->email; 
           
           //pego a ultima atividade que eu gravei na session;     
           $lastVisitTime  = $_SESSION['last_visited'];        
             
            //verifico o time gravado no tempo  
            $verificar =  $this->login_cliente_model->checarTempoSession($email);
            $cincominutos = $verificar->ultima_atividade;
          
          //veririco se o tempo inativo é menor ou igual ao gravado no banco
          if ($lastVisitTime <= $cincominutos) {  
                  
                  //se for ele faz o update pra mudar a ultima atividade do banco
                  $ultima_atividade = time()+(5 * 60);
                  $this->login_cliente_model->updateSession($ultima_atividade, $email);
                  
                  $retorno['erro'] = 0;
                  $retorno['msg']  = 'Ativo';
                  $retorno['verificarSessao']  =  $lastVisitTime;

                  header('Content-Type: application/json');
                  echo json_encode($retorno);
                  exit;

              } else {

                  //se não ele exclui a sessão aberta no banco e vai pra função logout 
                 $checharSessi = $this->login_cliente_model->checarSession($email);
              
                if($checharSessi  != FALSE){
                 
                   $this->login_cliente_model->deletarSession($email); 
                }
                
                  $retorno['erro'] = 60;
                  $retorno['msg']  = 'Inativo';
                  $retorno['verificarSessao']  = $lastVisitTime;

                  header('Content-Type: application/json');
                  echo json_encode($retorno);
                  exit;
          }

      }
      //verificar tempo de sessao
      public function expiraSessao()
      {
           if ($this->session->userdata('usuarioLogado')) {
           
                  $retorno['erro'] = 0;
                  $retorno['msg']  = 'Sessão expirou, acesse novamente.';
                  $retorno['verificarSessao']  =  '0';

                  header('Content-Type: application/json');
                  echo json_encode($retorno);
                  exit;
             
           }
             

      }
```

Aqui meu ajax que faz a verificação:

```
//Verificar inatividade na session
        var verificarInatividade= function (tempoParaChecarNovamenteEmSegundos) {
        $.ajax({
            type:"GET",
            url:"localhost/area_usuario/verificarInatividade", 
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (resposta){
            
            if (resposta.erro === 0) {  
                
                   var url = resposta.verificarUsuario;
                   console.log(url);
                    setTimeout(function() { verificarInatividade(tempoParaChecarNovamenteEmSegundos); }, tempoParaChecarNovamenteEmSegundos * 60000);
            } else {
                   
                      expiraSessao();
                     console.log(url);
                    setTimeout(function() { verificarInatividade(tempoParaChecarNovamenteEmSegundos); }, tempoParaChecarNovamenteEmSegundos * 60000);
            }  

            },
            error:function(){
                console.log(resposta);
            }
        });
        }

   //expira sessão    
        var expiraSessao= function() {
            $.ajax({
                type:"GET",
                url:"localhost/area_usuario/expiraSessao", 
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (resposta){
                   
                    window.location.replace("localhost/login_usuario/sessao_expirada");
                   
                },
                error:function(){
                    console.log(resposta);
                }
            });
        }
```

Agora faço o login e mesmo se deixo a janela inativa por mais de 5 minutos, ele continua atualizando o time no banco e não expira a sessão, e ele devia expirar se a sessão ficar inativa por 5 minutos, não sei pq ele está agindo assim, já revisei esse código mais de mil vezes, se puderem me ajudar me dando uma luz, sou grata.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A melhor solução é implementar seu próprio tempo limite de sessão. Use um registro de data e hora simples que indique a hora da última atividade (ou seja, solicitação) e atualize-a com cada solicitação:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY']) && (time() - $_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY'] > 1800)) {
    // last request was more than 30 minutes ago
    session_unset();     // unset $_SESSION variable for the run-time 
    session_destroy();   // destroy session data in storage
}
$_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY'] = time(); // update last activity time stamp
```

A atualização dos dados da sessão com cada solicitação também altera a data de modificação do arquivo da sessão, para que a sessão não seja removida pelo coletor de lixo prematuramente.

Você também pode usar um carimbo de data / hora adicional para gerar novamente o ID da sessão periodicamente para evitar ataques a sessões como a fixação da sessão :

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['CREATED'])) {
    $_SESSION['CREATED'] = time();
} else if (time() - $_SESSION['CREATED'] > 1800) {
    // session started more than 30 minutes ago
    session_regenerate_id(true);    // change session ID for the current session and invalidate old session ID
    $_SESSION['CREATED'] = time();  // update creation time
```

Comment: obrigado, vou dá uma estudada no seu código e tentar implementar aqui

Comment: mas essas duas verificações eu faço separada?, pq fazendo essa primeira verificação e essa segunda para a sessão não ser removida pelo coletor de lixo, está fazendo deslogar de qualquer jeito